# Is a WEI score of 9.9 even possible with today's hardware?

Tags: windows-8, windows-experience-index

I have read many reports online of people who are trying to max the new WEI in Windows 8 to the 9.9 score, but haven't found anyone who actually made it happen.

Is 9.9 even possible with today's hardware? And if so, what would be needed to get there?

Comment: Besides hacking it? http://www.jason-saggers.com/?p=775

Comment: @AthomSfere Yes, obviously :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but requires extreme hardware and a *ton* of money to purchase said hardware.

In terms of data storage, one would probably need to get a few SSDs and RAID them using RAID 0, as done here; http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96dWOEa4Djs&safety_mode=true&safe=active.

In terms of processors, you would need to be using at least 2 physical processors (which if I can recall is the maximum that windows 8 pro can use) with as many cores as possible and clocked as fast as possible, so i would say 2 intel Xeon 4GHz 10 core processors (this model http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processor-comparison/processor-specifications.html?proc=53576).

When it comes to graphics, you would need to be using workstation GPUs as they have higher performance than any gaming GPU, and because power comes in numbers you would also want more than one of these GPUs. Think of 4 Nvidia Quadro 6000 workstion GPUs packed into one computer (and again, heres a link to the site that has the info on Quadro GPUs http://www.nvidia.com/object/quadro-desktop-gpus.html). Because (If i am remembering correctly) the WEI does not account for networked GPU blocks, like the Nvidia Grid GPU cluster, these GPUs must be in the computer you are getting a rating from.

Finally, the RAM portion of the WEI. Simply enough, you would need to have the maximum amount of RAM that your computer could possibly have- the maximum permitted by the operating system and the maximum that the processor could recognize. If your motherboard couldn't handle all that RAM then you would need a RAM expansion of some sort.

Comment: Don't forget the all so important RAM clock timings - clocked most tightly.

Comment: ah, yes, I forgot about that.

Comment: And with all that set up, you will get a 9.8. That's what you wanted...right? right?

Comment: I dunno man, maybe. Disregard this post, it's way outdated, and I've since built a rig that performs to those specifications, finding that not even most of this is required to get such a rating.